# How do I stop Firefox developer tools inspector from collapsing HTML elements behind ellipsis?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

[image]

See the "..." before "layout-1c"? Firefox seems to have some rules defined for when it should collapse a lengthy element attribute. I want to disable this. Just show me everything, always. How?

EDIT double-clicking the attribute is not good enough. It loses wrapping and makes you manually scroll through a ton. Firebug does everything right from the get-go and I'd like the same behavior for the built-in inspector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the official [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings) it explains how we can tweak whether to truncate or not, and also how many characters will be shown before being truncated:

> **Truncate DOM attributes** 
> By default, the Inspector truncates DOM attributes that are more than 120 characters long. Uncheck this box to prevent this behavior. This setting works by toggling the about:config preference "devtools.markup.collapseAttributes". To change the threshold at which attributes are truncated, you can edit the about:config preference "devtools.markup.collapseAttributeLength".

There is a convenient checkbox in developer tools.
To find it click the three dots in the upper-right corner and go to Settings:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Truncating long attribute strings is, so far, a feature of the Firefox inspector, as in some cases, attributes may be really long and make it hard to use the tool. Think of base-64 image data-URLs for example.

I understand that this feature might not always be wanted, but for this to change, the inspector's code needs to be changed, there isn't a setting you can use. 2 options:

- Increase the limit after which strings are truncated to make sure only really long attributes are,
- Or add a setting (off by default to preserve today's behavior) to turn this off entirely.

But to answer the original question, no you can't disable this (other than by changing the code, or writing an addon that would monkey-patch this).

Answer (score 1):

You can double-click the attribute value to show the collapsed content. Note that this is a non-persistent solution.

Comment: Yep, known, but it's still non-optimal. Thanks for reminding me to edit this into the original q.

Answer (score 0):

The most optimal workaround speed-wise seems to be right-click "Edit as HTML".

Fortunately we have a bug filed now https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1198073